# Answering questions based on one's own intellect

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I am not sure if I should ask this on meta or on main. This is more about Islam though and little about this site.

I tend to answer question from Islamic point of view first but if I found a weakness there I also give a realistic point of view. Is that acceptable being a Muslim? Do I have to agree with everything the Quran says or I can give the actual perspective that we Muslims are never taught in schools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are a Q&A site about Islam, therefore answers should *always* be given according to an Islamic point of view.

However, what exactly constitutes an "Islamic point of view" is somewhat subjective.  Except for *laa ilaha illallah muhammadan rasulullah* there's not really a whole lot that self-identifying Muslims unanimously agree upon.

The traditional schools tend to restrict *ijtihad* to only those knowledgeable enough to make sound decisions, recommending the laymen follow the opinions of established scholars rather than try to make their own (possibly faulty) interpretations.  However, there are extant Muslim groups that are more lenient in this regard, who place more emphasis on personal *ijtihad* (Qur'an-only Muslims are particularly fond of this, I believe); so long as the result is rationally derived from and in accordance with the primary sources, it would be considered an acceptable interpretation.

As such, I feel that personal interpretations of the primary sources do have their place on this site, as long as they are reasonable, rational and clearly phrased as personal interpretations rather than scholarly opinion.

Such personal interpretations would still need to be in accordance with Islam (obviously, since this is an Islam Q&A), but I feel the voting mechanism will be a better judge of that than any attempts on my part to draw a clear line around what is, and what is not, "Islam."

Comment: agreed in most part. although allowing personal interpretations of the Qur'an and Hadith, lead to more confusion than clarity on the matter. to an outsider, it would seem ridiculous to see varying, sometimes conflicting opinions that are otherwise quite clear to someone who follows the verdict of their scholar/school of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Typically accepting Quran is kind of considered a minimal requirement for being a Muslim. (I guess there is an issue about what we mean by accepting Quran, e.g. some people who consider themselves to be Muslims may not agree with what is written in Quran as being exactly what is said by God, e.g. some modern reformist Muslim thinkers.)

I guess it might be fine if it is properly distinguished and it is not just personal opinion (that would lead to extended discussions w.h.p.).

But I also feel that it is needed to provide support and evidence for the expressed view from Islamic teachings and sources (or in some cases personal experience). Otherwise it looks like a personal opinion and the relation with Islam is not clear.

Comment: +1 for good answer