# is not to get answers of deen on this website?

Tags: discussion

Its haram to have a fatwa from a non known person so I think we should stop each other here about fiqh and such things ? unless scholars are people who answer

Comment: beacuse that not known person could be kafr really .. or not good muslim .. or fasq(فاسق) .. or not having a lot of info of deen .. thats why I say fatwa is taken in masjd or websites like islamweb and islamqa ... but here............... I don't think it is halal

Answer (score 3):

This website is strictly [*not a fatwa site*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Everybody here can answer the question [according to an Islamic point of view](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/380/3487)..

What is advisable when it comes to technical questions is that the answer provide references from fatwa, hadees and/or Quranic verses to bolster it.

Please go through the follow meta discussion to get a feel of how this site works:

- [Who can answer questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/101/3487)
- [No Tolerance for Intolerance](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/239/3487)
- [Disagreement should not be a basis for down-voting](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/746/3487)
- [Answering questions based on one's own intellect](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/3487)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer: I am not a scholar.**

I think the OP is correct.  I've been using this site for about two years.  I have asked a few questions and posted a few answers.  I have not encountered any other user here who could verifiably be labelled "scholar".  Maybe there are scholars here, but it's impossible to know who they are.

In fact, in the words of one of our Moderators, posting on [an unrelated question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/522) -

> i doubt most (if any) of our high-rep users consider themselves "experts" or "professionals"

Although this is clearly not a fatwa site, it seems that there are Muslims who are taking advice from this site, *instead of* talking to their local sheikh or scholar.  Since there is no way to know whether the person giving the advice is actually qualified to answer, this seems very dangerous.

Imagine if there were a medical site (doctor.stackexchange.com?), where people could ask medical questions and where members of the public could offer replies, such as "my grandmother always said that lemon juice and cinnamon was the best cure for throat cancer"; and where the "score" of an answer was determined by public voting, not by the qualifications of the respondent.  I think everyone would agree that such a site would do more harm than good.

And yet here, we are giving medicine for the soul, not for the body.  How much more harm are we doing here?

The best answer to almost every question on this site is "go and talk to a sheikh or scholar whom you trust, and follow what they tell you".  Any other answer has no right to be here.  But we actually encourage unqualified people to give answers, via the voting system.  The community is not large enough to be able to reliably distinguish which answers are "correct and mainstream", which are "not mainstream", and which are "just wrong".  And as the OP points out, it is (at least, in my unscholarly opinion) a sin for someone who doesn't have the right level of knowledge to answer the kinds of questions we have here.

Moreover, even asking a question here is enjoining a sin - it's encouraging unqualified people to give their opinions as answers.  So if this site encourages haram, why is it here?  Can anyone point out any attribute of this site that suggests that its existence is halal?

Insha Allah, I will be asking the administrators to remove my user profile from this site, along with my 3 questions and 13 answers.  Unless anyone can satisfy my doubts about this site, it is one haram that I no longer want to be associated with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that the questions are asking about fiqh the problem is that the questions are very unclear about who they are asking and then they get answers from anyone.  If someone wants a fatwa I don't think there's a problem with that it's just they need to make it clear that they're looking for a fatwa from a scholar and which school or sect they want the answer for and that way anyone who answers the question without the right expertise will be unwelcome.

We should discourage people from asking unclear questions and writing bad answers but we shouldn't assume that everyone who asks a question only wants an answer from a trained scholar or that they are unable to recognize a bad answer when they see one that clearly answers what they ask.