# What about the Islamic State?

Tags: discussion

I recently commented on a question criticising the belief of the so called Islamic State, al Qaeda, Boko Haram, etc. I was told by a member that I could not use such language / disrespect their beliefs. If this forum prevents people from vehemently opposing terrorism, do they realise this is a crime and illegal? If we Muslims can't stand up and speak out against such tyranny, why blame the world for the reputation of Islam?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that's kinda not what we're here for. We are a Q&A site about the topic of Islam and in general, [we prefer to avoid people vehemently opposing each other](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22) because a bunch of yelling doesn't actually help users get *actual answers* to their questions.

If you want to vehemently oppose someone, there's countless public forums and chat sites out there already that allow that sorta thing: Knock yourself out. But since they also tend to suck at answering actual questions, we are not one of them.

Comment: I agree, but the question of ISIS is related to Islam isn't it? I don't think it should be a problem for me to criticise terrorism, is it?

Comment: @SaadSheikh We focus on questions and answers here. Argument and debate is just noise that gets in the way of that. See also https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22

Comment: I see. Then I will clear myself using a question.

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this here: [Are there any groups of Muslims excluded from Islam.SE?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1910/17163)  Basically, I worry that Islamic State members (or sympathizers) might join the site and benefit from the free publicity.  A cunning IS user might use the site correctly, but e.g. selectively use radical fatawa to push a certain agenda.

I still don't know the answer, as there's two opposing points of view:

1. As goldPseudo writes, we're not here to bash each other's beliefs, no matter how unorthodox those beliefs are.
2. StackExchange is bound by US law; see the [content policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) page.  And [Islamic State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant) is considered a terrorist organization by virtually everyone except possibly the Islamic State (including the US), and surely some of its content is illegal or "I'm not sure if this is legal".

I think what to do here goes beyond the scope of an average user, and possibly beyond the scope of the diamond moderators.  None of us are supposed to "pick sides".

However, that being said, we are able to critically and respectfully question points that are raised, ideally by asking questions and/or giving better-written and better-referenced answers.

Comment: I agree! But if we can't reject terrorism and stand for peace, then we are complacent!